# I only want to import the last 20 text files into excel from a folder

Tags: excel-2010

Currently, the folder I'm importing from has 16,000 files and I only need the latest ones. The amount of lines wouldn't be so bad if it didn't break Excel every time it tried to run. The code I'm using imports them all:

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim folder As folder
Dim file As file
Dim FileText As TextStream
Dim TextLine As String
Dim Items() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim cl As Range

' Get a FileSystem object
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

' get the directory you want
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("X:\TMS\TRUCK_OUT")

' set the starting point to write the data to
Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)

' Loop thru all files in the folder
For Each file In folder.Files
' Open the file
Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

' Read the file one line at a time
Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
    TextLine = FileText.ReadLine

    ' Parse the line into | delimited pieces
    Items = Split(TextLine, "|")

    ' Put data on one row in active sheet
    For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
        cl.Offset(0, i).Value = Items(i)
    Next

    ' Move to next row
    Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
Loop

' Clean up
FileText.Close
Next file

Set FileText = Nothing
Set file = Nothing
Set folder = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You can check the last modified date and loop through only those files which falls in your desired timelines.

Comment: @Pankaj Jaju If you wouldn't mind, could you show me how to code that in? I'm not very strong in VBA or coding in general.

Comment: Let me give it a shot. Are you only interested in TXT files?

Comment: Yes, that's all that's available to me.

Comment: Check the code that i have posted. I have assumed that your folder only contains *.txt files and hence i didnt do any validation/filtering there

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following code - I have commented the extra line of code that i have added

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim folder As folder
    Dim file As file
    Dim FileText As TextStream
    Dim TextLine As String
    Dim Items() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim fileModDate As Date 'PANKAJ - Added the variable

    ' Get a FileSystem object
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject

    ' get the directory you want
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop")

    ' set the starting point to write the data to
    Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)

    ' Loop thru all files in the folder
    For Each file In folder.Files

        fileModDate = file.DateLastModified 'PANKAJ - Added this to get the last modified date for each file
        If fileModDate > #1/20/2014 1:00:00 PM# Then 'PANKAJ - Added this to get the desired file based on modified date
            ' Open the file
                Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

                ' Read the file one line at a time
                Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
                    TextLine = FileText.ReadLine

                    ' Parse the line into | delimited pieces
                    Items = Split(TextLine, "|")

                    ' Put data on one row in active sheet
                    For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
                        cl.Offset(0, i).Value = Items(i)
                    Next

                    ' Move to next row
                    Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
                   ' Clean up
                    FileText.Close
                Loop

        End If

    Next

    Set FileText = Nothing
    Set file = Nothing
    Set folder = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried it and it won't import anything now :( Thanks for the effort.

Comment: You might have to change the dates (currently it is hardcoded as 1/20/2014 1:00:00 PM) and date format (check your system date seetings).